# Deleting rows in a list

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

I have a queue setup that users can add cases to before submitting them. I currently have it so that they can type the row number of the case they want to delete; however, I need to make it so that they can press a button beside the row and have it delete that specific row.

I already set up the button to generate on each row. I just cannot figure out how to correlate that button with that row. This is the code I have so far:

CLASS-

```
public class MassAddCaseNotes {


    public Case_Note__c Case_Notes                    {get; set;}
    public List<Case> cases                           {get; private set;}
    public Map<Id, Boolean> selectedCases             {get; set;}
    public Case filterCase                            {get; set;}    
    public String sortField                           {get; set;}
    public boolean direction                          {get; set;}
    public List<Case_Note__c> queue                   {get; set;}
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController allCases  {get; set;}
    public Integer rowToRemove                        {get; set;}




    private final String selectCasesQuery = 'SELECT Id, CaseNumber, RecordType.Name, Contact.Name, Account.Name, Opened_Date__c, ClosedDate, Program_Location_Assignment__c, Referring_Agency__r.Name ' +
                                            'FROM Case ' +
                                            'WHERE Status=\'Open\' AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = \'Case\' AND IsActive = true)';

    public MassAddCaseNotes (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
   {
           queue = new List<case_Note__c>();
           Case_Notes = new Case_Note__c(); 
           filterCase = new Case();
           direction = true;
         //selectCases();
           direction = false;

   }

    public void selectCases() 
    {
        if (sortField == null) sortField = 'CaseNumber';
        String filter = '';
        if (filterCase.RecordTypeId != null) filter += ' AND RecordTypeId = \'' + filterCase.RecordTypeId + '\'';
        if (filterCase.ContactId != null) filter += ' AND ContactId = \'' + filterCase.ContactId + '\'';
        if (filterCase.AccountId != null) filter += ' AND AccountId = \'' + filterCase.AccountId + '\'';

        allCases = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(selectCasesQuery + filter +  ' ORDER BY ' + sortField + (direction ? ' ASC' : ' DESC')));
        allCases.setPageSize(1);
        updateCases();

    }


    public void sortCases() 
    {
        direction = !direction;
        selectCases();

    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious {get {return allCases.getHasPrevious();}}
    public Boolean hasNext {get {return allCases.getHasNext();}}

    public void previous() 
    {
        allCases.previous();
        updateCases();
    }

    public void next() 
    {
        allCases.next();
        updateCases();
    }

    private void updateCases() 
    {
        cases = allCases.getRecords();
        selectedCases = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
        for (Case c : cases) 
        {
            selectedCases.put(c.Id, false);
        }
    }


public void addtoqueue()
{
integer counter = 0;
        for (Case c : cases) 
        {
            if (selectedCases.get(c.Id)) 
            {

                Case_Note__c items = new Case_Note__c(
                    Case__c = c.Id,
                    Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c,
                    Contact_Name__c = filtercase.contactid,
                    Note__c = Case_Notes.Note__c 
                );

                 for(integer i = 0; i<= queue.size()-1; ++i)
                {
                    if(items == queue[i])
                    {
                         counter+=1;
                    }

                }                                
                    if(counter <= 0)
                    {
                         queue.add(items); 
                                            }
                    if(counter > 0 )
                    {                           
                    Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,''+' You are attempting to add a duplicate case to the queue.'));

                         }
                    }

            }
}




public void removelast()
{
queue.remove(queue.size()-1);
}

public void removeall()
{
queue.clear();
}



public void removeDesiredRow() 
{
    if(queue.size()>=rowToRemove&& rowToRemove> 0) 
    {
        queue.remove(rowToRemove-1);
        rowToRemove= null;
    }
  /*  if(rowToRemove == 999 || rowToRemove == 9999 || rowToRemove == 99999 || rowToRemove == 999999 || rowToRemove == 9999999)
    {
        queue.clear();
        rowToRemove= null;
    }
    if(queue.size()< rowToRemove && rowToRemove != 999 && rowToRemove != 9999 && rowToRemove != 99999 && rowToRemove != 999999 && rowToRemove != 9999999 || rowToRemove < 1)
    {  
        Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.error,''+'Please Enter A Valid Row To Delete'));
        rowToRemove= null;
    }*/
}




public PageReference save() 
{       
     addtoqueue();
     return null;
}


public PageReference submitCases()
{
if(queue.size()==0){
Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.info,''+' Your queue is currently empty.'));

}
if(queue.size()>0){
  integer i = 0;
  while(i<queue.size())
  {
     insert queue[i];
     i++;
  }

  queue.clear();


  }
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/MassAddCaseNotes');
  pg.setRedirect(true);
  return pg;
}

/*
public PageReference saveandclose() 
{
        List<Case_Note__c> note = new List<Case_Note__c>();
        for (Case c : cases) 
        {
            if (selectedCases.get(c.Id)) 
            {
                Case_Note__c s = new Case_Note__c(
                    Case__c = c.Id,
                    Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c,
                    Note__c = Case_Notes.Note__c
                );               

                note.add(s);
            }
        }
        insert note;  

     PageReference pg = new PageReference('/500/o');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
}
*/
}
```

PAGE-

```
<apex:page standardController="Case_Note__c" recordSetVar="MassAddCaseNotes" tabStyle="Case_Note__c" extensions="MassAddCaseNotes">







<apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Add Case Notes" />  
<apex:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
<apex:form style="width:450px" > 

    <apex:pageBlock title="Case Notes" id="block1">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Your Notes " columns="2" id="section1">
            <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.block1.section1}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]) </script>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote">Notes:  </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField style="width:300px;height:100px;" value="{!Case_Notes.Note__c}" id="CaseNote"  />
                <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote">Date:  </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Date__c}" id="Date" />
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Find Cases" columns="1">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> 
                <apex:outputLabel for="contactFilter">Contact Search: </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!filtercase.contactid}" required="true" id="contactFilter" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!selectCases}"   value="Filter" />                  
            </apex:panelGrid>

            <apex:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">          
               <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!cases}"  var="case"  id="case">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedCases[case.Id]}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Case Number" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="CaseNumber" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.CaseNumber}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Record Type" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="RecordType.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.RecordType.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Contact" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Contact.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Contact.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Account" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Account.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Account.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Date Opened" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Opened_Date__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Opened_Date__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                           </apex:PageBlockTable> 
                           <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save To Case Queue" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSave" immediate="false" />
            </apex:panelGrid>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form> 


<apex:variable var="rowcount" value="{!1}" />

<apex:form style="width:400px" > 
     <apex:pageBlock title="Case Queue" >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >





                      <apex:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="1" style="margin-top: 10px;"> 
                      <apex:commandButton action="{!submitCases}" value="Submit Notes"  status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSubmitCases" immediate="false" />
                     </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

        <apex:actionStatus layout="block" startText="Saving notes. . . " stopText="" id="retrieveSaveStatus" startStyle="color:green; font-style:italic" stopStyle="color:black;"/>
        <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false" />
                <br/>      

                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Queue" columns="1">
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="1" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                     <apex:commandButton value="Delete Row #: " action="{!removeDesiredRow}"/>
                     <apex:inputText value="{!rowToRemove}" style="width:30px" /> 
                     <apex:commandButton value="Delete all " action="{!removeall}"/>
                    </apex:panelGrid>

                        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!queue}" var="que">
                         <apex:column >
                          {!rowcount} <apex:variable var="rowcount" value="{!rowcount+1}" />
                          <apex:commandButton value="Delete: "   action="{!removeDesiredRow}"  />
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Contact Name" value="{!que.Contact_Name__c}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Case Number" value="{!que.Case__c}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Date" value="{!que.Date__c}"/>
                     </apex:pageblocktable>  



                </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>  


</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

This is a screen shot of the queue
[image: Case Queue]

This is the block of code that specifically deals with the queue

```
<apex:variable var="rowcount" value="{!1}" />

<apex:form style="width:400px" > 
     <apex:pageBlock title="Case Queue" >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >





                      <apex:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="1" style="margin-top: 10px;"> 
                      <apex:commandButton action="{!submitCases}" value="Submit Notes"  status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSubmitCases" immediate="false" />
                     </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

        <apex:actionStatus layout="block" startText="Saving notes. . . " stopText="" id="retrieveSaveStatus" startStyle="color:green; font-style:italic" stopStyle="color:black;"/>
        <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false" />
                <br/>      

                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Queue" columns="1">
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="1" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                     <apex:commandButton value="Delete Row #: " action="{!removeDesiredRow}"/>
                     <apex:inputText value="{!rowToRemove}" style="width:30px" /> 
                     <apex:commandButton value="Delete all " action="{!removeall}"/>
                    </apex:panelGrid>

                        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!queue}" var="que">
                         <apex:column >
                          {!rowcount} <apex:variable var="rowcount" value="{!rowcount+1}" />
                          <apex:commandButton value="Delete: "   action="{!removeDesiredRow}"  />
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Contact Name" value="{!que.Contact_Name__c}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Case Number" value="{!que.Case__c}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Date" value="{!que.Date__c}"/>
                     </apex:pageblocktable>  



                </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

And this specifically deals with the removal of individual rows.

```
public void removeDesiredRow() 
{
    if(queue.size()>=rowToRemove&& rowToRemove> 0) 
    {
        queue.remove(rowToRemove-1);
        rowToRemove= null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Javascript Remoting](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) for this which gives you the benefit of a more light-weight solution, and conforming your `<apex:pageBlockTable>` to Salesforce's list views. For example:

[image]

Here's a sample code:

**Controller**

```
public class MassAddCaseNotes {

    @RemoteAction
    public static void deleteCase(Id caseNoteId) {
        delete new Case_Note__c(Id = caseNoteId);
    }

}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteCaseNote(caseNoteId) {
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.MassAddCaseNotes.deleteCase}',
            caseNoteId, 
            function (result, event) {
                if (event.status) {
                    // Refresh the page after deleting the record.
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
</script>

...

<apex:pageblocktable value="{!queue}" var="que">
    <apex:column>
        <a onclick="deleteCaseNote('{!que.id}')">Delete</a>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: I have put this into my code and it looks great, the "delete button" shows up and when I mouse over it, it turns blue with an underline but I cannot click on it. My cursor is just a text cursor when I scroll over it.

Comment: Write this instead: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteCaseNote('{!que.id}')">Delete</a>`

Comment: It certainly is close. It has the hand cursor and lets me click it. But nothing happens.

Comment: Strange. First, open your dev console to see if you're getting any javascript errors. Then check if the javascript `function deleteCaseNote(caseNoteId)` gets invoked when you click the "Delete" link. If it does, check if you get a debug log from SFDC (this will be due to the `@RemoteAction` being invoked).

Comment: I don't see any javascript errors and I am unsure how to go about checking to see if the `function deleteCaseNote(caseNoteId)` gets invoked when 'Delete' is clicked. I have not used the dev console very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters inside `apex:CommandButton`. So, as you emit the rows in your table, you can have a child element for your `apex:commandButton`, which is an `apex:param`, which will call a setter on your controller prior to processing the action of your `apex:commandButton`.

For example, you could use the id value of your iterator, que, as the identifier, instead of trying to do the `rowCount` thing. Modify `removeDesiredRow()` to expect `que.id` in a `rowToRemove` variable, instead of the `rowCount`.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Delete: " action="{!removeDesiredRow}">
  <apex:param name="rowToRemove" value="{!que.id}" assignTo={!rowToRemove}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

Simply add some `rerender` behavior to the `apex:commandButton`, to keep your data table up to date. You can also get fancy and use `<apex:actionSupport>` and `<apex:actionRegion>` if you want an AJAX solution without messing with JavaScript manually.

Comment: if we want confirm dialog box before delete then how you will process.